# Connecting to samba ubuntu server from linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, connection, users

In these days I'm setting up a small network with about twenty computers. The users of this network used windows before (now they use linux mint) and they need to access samba ubuntu folders simply using their name (which is same as their login) and password (there's no problem for them with typing access data). In that case I need the simplest way for them to access it. I was thinking of using links (I found out it's impossible) and bookmarks are working well, but I need the solution to be cloneable (I'm cloning user accounts to another computers in the network - /etc/passwd and home directories). Is there any way how to do it simply?

EDIT: If the things upper are not simply possible, please tell me at least some way how to connect to a single server called "Server-desktop".

Comment: It's totally unclear what your problem or objective is.  The title suggests you can't connect to the server.  Then you proceed to talking about links/bookmarks which sounds like web lingo, and all of a sudden an extra server springs up ... what do you need help with?

Comment: I can connect server by File->Connect and I can create bookmark for it, but I need some way to connect server directly from some shortcut as it's possible in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your whole network is Linux based - which I think your question implies - why not just set up NFS shares and take Samba out of the picture?  You could also use NIS+ or something similar to handle authentication/authorization and allow the users single signin and access of their folders.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNISHowTo